# Stripe webhook doesn't execute callback. Or am I missing something?

Tags: next.js, async-await, stripe-payments, webhooks, strapi

I have a project in Next.js with Strapi & Stripe. There is a webhook that is executed after successful payment and after that, it should run `markProductAsSold` callback, and it does but only at localhost. Also if I run only a callback (idk. on button click somewhere on a page) it's working on stage and localhost!

**Webhook code:**

```js
export const config = {
    api: {
        bodyParser: false,
    },
};

export default async function webhookHandler(req, res) {
    const stripe = new Stripe(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_STRIPE_SECRET, {
        apiVersion: '2022-11-15',
    });

    if (req.method === 'POST') {
        const buf = await buffer(req);
        const sig = req.headers['stripe-signature'];
        const webhookSecret = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_STRAPI_WEBHOOK_KEY;

        let event;

        try {
            if (!sig || !webhookSecret) return;

            event = stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(buf, sig, webhookSecret);
        } catch (error) {
            return res.status(400).send(`Webhook error: ${error.message}`);
        }

        if (event.data.object.status === 'succeeded') {
            await markProductAsSold(event.data.object.metadata.MarkAsSold);
        }
    }

    res.status(200).send();
}
```

**Callback code**

```js
const markProductAsSold = async (slug: string) => {
    const findProduct = await fetch(
        `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_DATABASE_URL}/api/products?filters[slug][$eq]=${slug}`
    );

    const data = await findProduct.json();

    const isSold = data.data[0].attributes.isSold;

    const productData = {
        ...data.data[0]
    };
    productData.attributes.isSold = !isSold;

    await fetch(
        `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_DATABASE_URL}/api/products/${productData.id}`, {
            method: 'PUT',
            headers: {
                Authorization: `Bearer ${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_STRAPI_TOKEN}`,
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                data: productData.attributes,
            }),
        }
    );

    return productData;
};

export default markProductAsSold;
```

All data like `metadata.MarkAsSold` or env's are 100% valid and triple checked. I just don't know where could be a problem cause callback doesn't work only after being fired on stage by Stripe webhook.

**Solved**

It turns out that my callback wasn't running after everything was triggered by Stripe. Idk. why but when I moved `markProductAsSold` function directly into `if (event.data.object.status === 'succeeded')` it started to working.

Answer (score 1):

you had to register your app in production. you should already have run this commmand for development.

```
 // installed stripe cli 
 // api/webhook your enpoint
stripe listen --events checkout.session.completed --forward-to localhost:3000/api/webhook
```

similarly you should register your production endpoint.

you can follow [webhooks/go-live docs](https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks/go-live)

Answer (score 0):

Verify you webhook secret key, remember there is two keys for webhook one that work on in localhost and second for production in stripe developer signing secret ,[image]